# 3d model thickened but still hollow; problems printing it

Tags: blender, tinkercad

I started fiddling with Blender this week as I bought a 3D model of a backpack that I wanted to 3D print. In order to get Lychee to print it, I had to use a back-and-forth combination of Blender and an stl repair service online. When Lychee was finally able to fill the holes and accept the geometry, I realized that the model that I originally thickened was still hollow inside. When printed, certain surfaces fail to print because it is too thin.  Right now I'm trying to use Tinkercad to import my stl file, make it hollow, put on solid over it to make a mold, make the mold hollow, and fill the mold with a solid to get a positive of my 3D model.

It doesn't seem to work, and I'd like to ask for some help to find a solution. Please see below what my 3D model looks like when sliced :

[image]

[image: Hollowed mold, solid, and 3D model that is part of the hollowed mold]

I used the displacement tool to thicken my model because the solidify tool was causing issues when importing the model in Lychee. Maybe I was doing something wrong?

Comment: Please refrain from posting updates/comments as answers. Instead edit your question and update that, or comment under the relevant answer. The answer section is only for solutions to your problem... Also, please take the [tour] to better understand how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: Could you share your STL file ?

Answer (score 0):

If the thickness (Solidify) was added in Blender, you can try unchecking the only rim check box on the Solidify modifier.

Comment: I unchecked the box, to no avail. I have yet to find a way to make the whole thing thick *and* solid.